# Как выбрать записи за несколько дней?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица votes с датами. За один день бывает много записей. Надо выбрать записи за последние три дня или за три дня до опредленной даты.
Собиралась взять максимальную дату, для каждой строчки выполнить datediff относительно максимальной даты, получится число, и выбрать только те строчки, у которых этот datediff возвращает значение < 3.
Подскажите пожалуйста, правильно ли я делаю, или есть другой способ?

Таблица достаточно простая

```
create table votes (id int, creationDate datetime, userId int)
```

Comment: Было бы неплохо увидеть структуру БД...

Comment: @Vega Лучше взять текущую дату или ту которая нужна, вычесть из нее 3 и выбирать все записи которые больше полученной даты. Из дат можно вычитать 3 дня обычным арифметическим вычитанием. `select * from table where date_field>getdate()-3`

Comment: @Mike мне нужна максимальная дата, она меняется. Я так понимаю, что надо получить max(date), а потом как получить -3 дня непонятно.

Comment: @Streletz структура простая, я добавила sql для ее создания в вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучше сначала получить требуемую дату, вычесть из нее 3 дня и подбирать записи большие этой даты:

```
 select * from votes
  where creationDate > (select max(creationDate)-3 from votes)
```

При наличии индекса по полю `creationDate` это позволит значительно ускорить запрос, т.к. и получение максимума и поиск всех больших дат будут идти по нему. При применении же datediff на каждой записи полностью исключает использование индексов и приведет к полному сканированию таблицы.

Для задания конкретной даты, либо вычислять заранее -3 дня, если это затруднительно, то так:

```
  select * from votes
   where creationDate > Cast('2016-15-01' as datetime)-3
```

P.S. В зависимости от настроек MsSQL сервера формат даты может быть разным. год-месяц-день или год-день-месяц

Comment: спасибо. а как указать определенную дату вместо max(creationDate)?

Comment: @Vega дополнил ответ